# Can't link CSS file to HTML file

Tags: html, css

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet” type=”text/css” href=“style.css”/>
<title>Brian’s Page</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class=“jumbotron”>
<div class=“container”>
<h1>Brian Experience</h1>
<p><strong>Greetings!</strong></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class=“nav”>
 <div class=“container”>
<ul class=“list”>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Videos</li>
    <li>Pictures</li>
    <li>About</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div


</body>



</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.jumbotron h1 {font-size: 100px;
color:blue;}

.nav li {display: inline;
list-style-type: none;}
```

My css file won;t link to my html file. They are in the same folder. And the name is correct, and the file is correctly saved as a .css file. Is there an error in my code? I have been searching forums and google to no avail :( Any suggestions? :)

Comment: bootstrap connected?

Comment: Check if there is a request for the css file. To do it: open network tab in your browser's html inspector, and reload the page. It may be a permissions problem.

Comment: how do i check to see if there is a request for the css file on google chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you copy pasted the contents from a website. When you copy pasted, the quotes had an inner style hidden with it that your browser didnt recognize. So,

Replace

```
<link rel="stylesheet” type=”text/css” href=“style.css”/>
```

with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
```

You will have to change all the `”` that you have used in your HTML to `"` inorder for the HTML to work as expected.

Comment: you'll have to change all the `”` used in your HTML..for example, the `”` in `<div class=“jumbotron”>`

Comment: i deleted all the " and rewrote them

Comment: you'll have to change the `“` in all the `div`s..eg:`<div class=“jumbotron”>`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you handle the *type* and *href* incorrectly.
Instead of using **”** you must use **"**.

In order for your stylesheet to get called, your stylesheet link should look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

I hope it helps.