# Linking CSS rule to child sheets

Tags: html, css

I'd like to be be able to link to the rule for the class "button" in multiple sheets and have it defined in one sheet such that I only need to edit it once to edit all my buttons.

Example:

mystyle.css reads:

```
.button{ 
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 45px;
  width: 140px;
  background-color: #9999ff;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 6px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

I want when I create a new page to be able to say something like

```
.button {
  url:("../mystyle.css/.button")
}
```

Comment: You want to do this in `HTML` with a `<link>` tag. With both files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't link CSS file to HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30015865/cant-link-css-file-to-html-file)

Comment: sorry but this is not how CSS works ...

Answer (score 1):

This one was down to me not understanding how HTML loads styles.

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../mystyle.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./newpage.css">
</head>
```

Will load all the CSS for the buttons and then if both files define the same element, style according to newpage.css

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the [`@import` at-rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40import):

```
@import "buttons.css";
```

or by using a CSS processor such as [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/) to combine the files at build time.

You could also import multiple CSS files into a single HTML document by using multiple `<link>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include your base css in your child css sheet like;

```
@import url("base.css");
```